# Erro ao executar o projeto no Android Studio

Tags: android

Bom estou recebendo um erro, e preciso de uma ajuda de vocês meus amigos, vou postar a minha grandle e o erro que está acontecendo.

Quando executo meu projeto ele me exibe a mensagem de erro no biuld da seguinte forma.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments
>   [com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0] on repository container of
>   type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK
>   Manager.

A minha Grandle está assim !!

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Como devo proceder para corrigir esse problema ?

Answer (score 5):

> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.

Como a própria mensagem diz, você deve instalar a *Biblioteca de Suporte*, siga os passos:

1. Inicie o ***Android SDK Manager***
2. Na janela do *SDK Manager*, role até o final da lista *Packages*, encontre a pasta *Extras* e, se necessário, expanda-a para mostrar o conteúdo.
3. Selecione o item ***Android Support Repository***
4. Clique no botão ***Install packages***

[image: Android SDK Manager]

Fonte: [Configuração da Biblioteca de Suporte](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup?hl=pt-br)

---

Outra solução é atualizar as dependências, principalmente *Gradle* para (ou outra mais recente):

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```